# Inserting spanish text in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

I do a HTTP GET call in Java to get content which may contain spanish characters, for example: Ñañez

But what I get as a response from Mysql - Ã‘aÃ±ez
So far I searched online and did the below:

1. Appended utf-8 as encoding in connection String(Using Java)
   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
2. Updated the table's encoding
   ALTER TABLE test CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

The problem is still there..
Anything I am missing??

Server is Tomcat 6

Comment: How does the result look when you execute the query directly against the SQL server using an SQL client?

Answer (score 0):

try altering table column

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `columnname` `columnname` VARCHAR(200) 
    CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

you must run this query before your insert query in mysql:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

Answer (score 0):

Mojibake is *usually* caused by

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

Include `characterEncoding=utf-8` in the connection string.